# Why do cylinders roll easily and not square or rectangular slabs?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Why do cylinders roll easily and not square or rectangular slabs?? Let us say both have same materiel and vertical dimensions? What is the reason for the slab always tends to slide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a block rotate due to friction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117010/)

Comment: Note that you need to raise the centre of mass of a square or triangle whilst trying to roll them.

Comment: These square wheels roll perfectly, indeed much more easily than cylinders in the analogous situation! https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10001.2-3-8.shtml

Answer (score 0):

A slab can slide, but it will not move unless the static friction force (which is proportional to the weight $Mg$ of the slab by the static friction coefficient $\mu_s$) is exceeded by the force $F$ pulling on the slab parallel to the surface on which it is supposed to slide. So, there will be no movement unless $$ F>\mu_s Mg $$
Alternatively, if you want to let it 'roll' (because the friction is terribly high), you will have to lift its center of mass. For a square prism slab, you will have to apply a force, high enough to lift its center of mass so that you get it rotating around its rib. Again, a minimum force is needed to get it moving.

A To get a cylinder rolling, you just need to overcome the rolling friction. The cylinder will roll if the force $F$, pulling on the cylinder is exceeding the friction force or $$ F>C_{rr} Mg $$ with $Mg$ the weight of the cylinder and $C_{rr}$ the coefficient of rolling resistance. $C_{rr}$ has the same function in rolling as  $\mu_s$ has in sliding, however it is much smaller. A rubber tire on concrete has a $C_{rr}$ of the order of 0.1, while rubber has a $\mu_s$ of the order of 1. This means that 
much smaller pulling force will be required to get a cylinder rolling than to get a slab sliding.

Comment: In fact, you shouldn't overcome the static friction of the cylinder. Otherwise it won't start rolling. The static friction is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, on a flat surface, one needs to raise a square's center of mass for it to roll: its center's distance from the ground varies cyclically between $r$ and $\sqrt{2}\,r$ as it rolls where $r$ is the square's halfwidth. So there is a *potential barrier* to the motion: one needs to input energy to raise the wheel's potential energy - and that of whatever it is linked to - to get it to move to its maximum potential energy point, which is when it is standing on a vertex. An advanced design might recover that potential energy as the wheel and vehicle it supports fall down into the potential energy trough, but it would still be a bumpy ride!

As a bit of fun, note that square wheels of the appropriate "radius" roll perfectly well on a road whose surface is a sequence of inverted catenaries. See [this link here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10001.2-3-8.shtml)