# Finding out the coefficient of friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

A cube is moving with constant velocity on a smooth horizontal surface. Surface is rough  beyond point $A$.The question is to find out the minimum value of coefficient of friction of surface such that the cube starts toppling as soon as it crosses point $A$.

[image]

---

To topple the cube there must be unbalanced torque .If F is the force that acts on the cube horizontally at a distance $x$ from the base of the cube (Assuming $a$ to be the side length of the cube).Then at critical condition of toppling $mg(a/2)=Fx$ From where we can find $F$ given $x$ or vice versa.But in the present question neither of two is given and I couldn't get how to approach this question.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction $f=\mu mg$ exerts a force to the left on the base of the cube. The deceleration $a=f/m$ of the cube causes an inertial (pseudo-) force $ma=f$ to act to the right on the COM of the cube. (This is similar to centrifugal force which acts radially outward on an object in circular motion, which accelerates radially inward.) These two equal and opposite forces constitute a couple which attempts to rotate the cube clockwise.

As the cube begins to rotate clockwise its weight transfers wholly on the lower right corner. The normal reaction $N$ acts vertically through this corner. Weight $W$ acting down on the COM and reaction $N=W$ acting upwards on the corner constitute another couple which attempts to rotate the cube anti-clockwise.

If the clockwise torque due to $f$ is greater than the anti-clockwise torque due to $W$, the cube will rotate. The torque due to $f$ increases as the cube tilts, whereas the torque due to $W$ decreases, until the *tipping point* is reached at which the COM is above the pivot.

See related questions [Why doesn't a block rotate due to friction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117010) and [Would this box on the floor rotate based on friction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79656).

---

You might wonder : Isn't there something missing here? Why doesn't $v$ come into this analysis? Experience tells us that the cube is more likely to topple if the velocity $v$ of the cube is high.

It takes time for the net torque to rotate the cube from its initial position past the tipping point. At this point the torque due to $W$ changes from anti-clockwise to clockwise and then promotes toppling instead of opposing it.

If $v$ is low the cube may have stopped decelerating before the COM reaches the tipping point. The torque due to $f$ then disappears, so there is only the anti-clockwise torque due to $W$ still acting. If $v$ is high the deceleration time is more likely to be long enough for the COM to pass the tipping point.

Even if the cube has stopped sliding over the rough surface before the cube reaches the tipping point, its angular momentum might be enough to carry it past that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have understood every line of your answer.But still one thought rolls over my mind.since the question asks that as soon as the cube reaches point $A$ it topples.so can we apply impulse momentum theorem here.Only two impulsive force normal reaction and thereby friction force which depends on normal reaction acts on the cube and normal reaction can change momentum in vertical direction and friction force in horizontal direction.But couldn't figure out the final velocity in both directions just at instant of  toppling.Any insights?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is implied by "the cube starts toppling *as soon as it crosses point A*." Does it mean a soon as the RH edge reaches A? Or the LH edge? If the cube does not start to topple when the LH edge reaches A, there does not seem to be any reason why it should start to topple later.

Comment: If there is an impulse (eg because friction is so high that the RH edge of the block is brought to rest immediately) this is like an instantaneous collision with an obstruction, as in [this MIT problem](http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/InClass/Raw/IC_Sol_W15D1-4.pdf). But I do not think there can be such an instantaneous collision, because the friction force is proportional to the area of overlap, which increases gradually from zero up to the maximum, constant value. ... If you have a potential solution, please post it for discussion in the JEE or Temp Phys Q & A chatroom.

Comment: thanks for the MIT link.I have a potential solution.please provide me access to Temp PhysQ&A chatroom.this room is read only for me.

Comment: Post in JEE Prep chatroom instead. More users will be able to comment.

Comment: I am posted it in the JEe prep chatroom